# Displaying Reversed Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I am trying to reverse a liked list in c++ but unfortunately I am unable to do that. Here is the entire program I am working on. I don't know where the problem is. The problem I think is either
`reverse()` 
or
`displayList()`

```
void reverse()
{
    struct node *curr = head;
    struct node *next = NULL;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;

        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}

void displayList()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << " ";

        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    createNode(100);
    createNode(310);
    createNode(150);
    createNode(300);
    createNode(500);

    cout << "Original List" << endl;

    displayList();

    cout << endl << "Reversed List" << endl;

    reverse();
    displayList();

    return 0;
}
```

When I comment `displayList()` when I first called it, it worked. Basically the function runs only one time.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] ([edit] your question)).  Also, what have you learned using your debugger, especially since it appears you're using globals for everything.

Comment: Where did your head go?

Comment: To be able to iterate from both ends you need a head and a tail. And put all your logic in a doubly linked list class. With push_front(int) and push_back(int) methods. With a head and a tail you don't need to reverse the list at all. Just follow the links in different directions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `displayList` to be a member function of some List type because there is no local variable `head` anywhere: You destroy your list (leaking all data) when iterating over it in `displayList`. Here are some fixes.

```
void displayList() const
{
    node* curr = head; 
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << curr->data << ' ';

        curr = curr->next;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

If you get into the habit of making functions `const` that are not supposed to change the object, your compiler would have spotted this for you.

Comment: I suspect `head` is a global variable.

Comment: @john I suspect you're right, looking at `main`. Well, it should be a member variable of a class. Perhaps OP will be motivated to write a class for the list.